# Using npm in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core, npm

Why should I use npm with asp.net core? Is there a difference between using npm and adding client-side libs like this?

[image][image]

Answer (score 2):

> Why should I use npm with asp.net core?

If your ASP.NET Core project has no dependency on any npm packages such as `React.js`/ `Angular`/ `Vue`/ e.t.c, you don't need to use npm to install client dependencies at all (Simply Pay as you go).

> Is there a difference between using npm and adding client-side libs like this?

Yes.

**The second way is invoking [`LibMan`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/libman/index?view=aspnetcore-2.1) instead of the `npm`** behind the scenes.

As the official document describes, **`LibMan` is a lightweight tool [written in C#](https://github.com/aspnet/LibraryManager)** to download popular libraries. When dealing with dependencies, LibMan is similar to npm in some way.

However, `Libman` will download libraries from CDNs(including [CDNJS](https://cdnjs.com/) and [unpkg](https://unpkg.com/#/)) instead of from [`npmjs`](https://npmjs.com) or other npm repositories.

Also, it's easy to custom the path of your dependency files. There's no need to copy files from `node_modules/`.